# The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I am getting the error as given below

"The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."

```
using (SecurityClient securityClient = new SecurityClient())
{                        
    SecurityService.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdRequest securityRequest =
        new GetIncomingPermissionsByIdRequest(Convert.ToInt32(recordId));
    SecurityService.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdResponse securityResponse =
        securityClient.GetIncomingPermissionsById(securityRequest);
    incomingPermissions = securityResponse.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdResult;
    SetPermissionFields();
    SetPermissionList();                  
    securityClient.Close();
}
```

In the above code I am able to send request but when it comes to the Response line and trying to get response it move to the fault state and getting the error mentioned above.I have checked the state of the SecurityClient before it moving to the response line,then it is in the created state.but when trying to get the response it move to fault state.

Will any one help me please.I have tried some of the methods mentioned in the stack but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the using...

The simple solution:

```
SecurityClient securityClient = new SecurityClient();

SecurityService.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdRequest securityRequest = new GetIncomingPermissionsByIdRequest(Convert.ToInt32(recordId));
SecurityService.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdResponse securityResponse = securityClient.GetIncomingPermissionsById(securityRequest);
incomingPermissions = securityResponse.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdResult;
SetPermissionFields();
SetPermissionList();                  
securityClient.Close();
securityClient.Dispose();
```

A more elegant solution:

Create a WCF Extension:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class WcfExtensions
    {
        public static void Using<T>(this T client, Action<T> work)
            where T : ICommunicationObject
        {
            try
            {
                work(client);
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException e)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException e)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                client.Abort();
                throw;
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

And then instantiate using the following syntax:

```
    new SecurityClient().Using(securityClient => 
        {
            SecurityService.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdRequest securityRequest = new GetIncomingPermissionsByIdRequest(Convert.ToInt32(recordId));
            SecurityService.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdResponse securityResponse = securityClient.GetIncomingPermissionsById(securityRequest);
            incomingPermissions = securityResponse.GetIncomingPermissionsByIdResult;
            SetPermissionFields();
            SetPermissionList();                  
        });
```

[Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx)